# Confusion about http-server vs using http in NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, http, httpserver

I'm trying to run an html file using NodeJS. I installed a command line node package called "http-server". When I run the html file using http-server, it opens just fine.

Where the problems start arising for me is when I try to host the same html file using NodeJS's html library. I tried running my html file using the code below, but it does not work as I would expect. The webpage is just a blank white page.

Why is this? What does the http-server package do that my regular code does not do?

Thank you for any help in advance!

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Just make sure you have index.html inside the project's directory.

Comment: I would normally expect the code to work, but it does not for me. I have my index.html file in the project's directory. When I visit the localhost site, only the name of the website appears on my Google Chrome tab. Nothing else appears on the window.

When I host the same file with "http-server", however, it loads the entire page. I'm not really sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that I was not including some of the necessary files when I was creating my NodeJS file. The code below solved my issue!

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'FOLDER_NAME')));
```

Comment: So you changed to use Express?

Comment: Yeah, someone above recommended it

Comment: In that case I don't think this answer best fits for the original question. I'm not suggesting deleting your answer, just to unmark it as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `fs.readFileSync('index.html');` with `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');` (__dirname is the directory the project is in)

Comment: That change seems to get the webpage started, but it seems that the core functionality of my website is missing.

Comment: When I run the webpage using the "http-server" module, everything in the website works perfectly. The page uses a webcam, which is perfectly functional when I use the http-server module. When I use the code I provided above with your changes, the webcam never even initializes. I'm not sure why this is happening...

Comment: That’s strange, but I don’t think I can answer why that happens. You might want to look into using Express, which will simplify your code a bit.